# How can I prevent my C# application from opening new windows during context menu?

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I'm working on some C# application to help myself learn C# a bit. I've been searching for a solution, but I can't seem to find one.

When my application minimizes, it shows a notifyicon in the system tray. When I right click it, a context menu pops up on the mouse. However, for each level of the menu and submenu, a blank window pops up on the taskbar until I exit that submenu or the contextmenu.

I don't know why, and I'd like to. I'd also like to know how to prevent that from happening.

### Edit

Also, in Visual C# Studio 2010, when debugging, is there a way to determine exactly which form/part of the code I've focused on, so that I could click one of those windows to see what exactly it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you showing the ContextMenu?  I suspect you are calling ContextMenu/ContextMenuStrip.Show(x,y) directly.  That will cause it to show in the taskbar.

Instead, assign your ContextMenu/ContextMenuStrip to the ContextMenu/ContextMenuStrip property of your NotifyIcon rather than manually showing it in the mouse click handler.  If it is used as part of ContextMenu/ContextMenuStrip property, it won't show in the taskbar.